# Benchmark script performance against CPU/RAM consumption for different parameters

Tags: cpu-usage, memory-usage

I have an image processing shell script that can be provided with different sets of parameters that all produce a valid output for me. I'm trying to identity the set of parameters that has the lowest resources (CPU/RAM) usage as this script is going to run on the cloud. Are there any tools I can use to benchmark? I'm looking for something that would give me the total cpu cycles used by the script or any other relevant data/metric that I could compare.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04, Shell: BASH

Example of what I am looking for:

```
magical-benchmark-tool -c pdftoppm -png test.pdf test
```

**Output**

```
time (seconds)   processor cycles   max memory used (MB)    mean memory used (MB)
--------------   ----------------   --------------------    --------------------
19               1253               250                     128
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to add operating system, version, and which imaging processing library, if you want specific discussion on tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify which shell you use, so I'm going to assume Bash.

---

For CPU ustage you can use `strace`.

```
strace -c script.sh
```

For a simple Hello World script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

**Output**

```
Hello World
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 17.70    0.000253          14        18           mmap
 11.69    0.000167          20         8           openat
  9.59    0.000137           9        14           rt_sigaction
  7.35    0.000105          13         8           fstat
  6.30    0.000090          15         6           mprotect
  5.60    0.000080          10         8           close
  5.32    0.000076          12         6           read
  5.11    0.000073          14         5           stat
  4.90    0.000070          70         1           execve
  3.50    0.000050          10         5           rt_sigprocmask
  2.59    0.000037          37         1           write
  2.24    0.000032          10         3           lseek
  2.24    0.000032          10         3           brk
  2.10    0.000030          10         3         2 ioctl
  1.89    0.000027           9         3         1 fcntl
  1.40    0.000020          20         1           munmap
  1.40    0.000020          20         1         1 access
  1.33    0.000019           9         2           getpid
  1.26    0.000018           9         2           prlimit64
  0.77    0.000011          11         1           dup2
  0.70    0.000010          10         1           sysinfo
  0.70    0.000010          10         1           getppid
  0.70    0.000010          10         1           arch_prctl
  0.63    0.000009           9         1           uname
  0.63    0.000009           9         1           getuid
  0.63    0.000009           9         1           getgid
  0.63    0.000009           9         1           getpgrp
  0.56    0.000008           8         1           geteuid
  0.56    0.000008           8         1           getegid
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.001429                   108         4 total
```

---

For memory you can use `top`.
While runnig top press <kbd>o</kbd> and type e.g. `COMMAND=bash` to show entries from the `COMMAND` column that are equal to `bash`.

Comment: Thanks! strace gives me what I want regarding CPU. Now I need to get some numbers regarding memory (max memory used, mean memory used during processing) from the command line.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you can use `top`. It's not perfect, but I'm not aware of any onther free solutions.
Also, if you find my answer useful, consider [accepting and/or upvoting it](https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers).